# Android Studio no reconoce ningún layout, aparte del MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, recyclerview

Resumen del proyecto: tengo una lista que debe mostrar los datos de una base de datos; hasta ahí todo bien. Usé un RecyclerView para mostrar los datos y diseñé un **layout** para colocar la información. ¿El problema?; no importa cuántos layouts cree, ni como se llamen, o si hago Activities, porque **no los reconoce, sólo al MainActivity**

[image: Ya tengo creado el layout *"item_rv"*, y lo llamo en la clase adaptador (del RecyclerView), pero no lo reconoce]

La fantástica opción que me da Android Studio es: crear un layout con ese nombre; que como ya existe no me va a dejar. Busqué problemas similares y encontré que **limpiando y reconstruyendo el código** se solucionaba, y no fue así.

Por favor, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, o me dé una sugerencia para hacerlo de otra forma. **¡Gracias!**

Comment: Solo tienes que cerrar y volver a abrir Android Studio y todo funcionará. Muchas veces pasa que al crear el layout no lo reconoce, así que cierra abre y funcionará.

Comment: Te sugiero agregues el contenido de item_rv.xml, revisa si este muestra algun error. Prueba invalidando cachè : File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart

Comment: Hola por favor responde a las preguntas de la comunidad, saludos.